# Laravel 5 setup model event to "clear up" pivot tables on model delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 to build a user based application.  Some models have a `manyToMany` relationship in my app and therefore I am using pivot tables.

When I delete a user from the system, I use this simple function:

```
/**
 * Delete user.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    return $this->user->whereId($id)->delete();
}
```

However, when the user is deleted, the rows in the pivot tables (for example `role_user)` do not get deleted.

I have read on the laravel site that I can use model events to "clear up" my pivot tables, but i'm really unsure how I would implement that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

Below is my current model setup:

```
namespace App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use App\Scopes\MultiTenantTrait;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, MultiTenantTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['cust_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status', 'activation_code'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * Boot the model.
     *
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($user)
        {
            $user->roles()->delete();
            $user->supervisors()->delete();
            $user->types()->delete();
            $user->rates()->delete();
            $user->miscs()->delete();
        });
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a boot method to your models, like the following:

```
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    // This is a deleting event on the model
    static::deleting(function($model) {
        $model->... //Here your model is still available

        // You could add something like this
        DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id', $model->id)->delete();
    })
}
```

But you can also extend the delete method in your models:

```
public function delete() {
    DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id', $this->id)->delete();
    parent::delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this in my model but the `static::deleted` part doesn't seem to get hit.  I've tried putting a die and dump inside that which never gets triggered.  Any idea?

Comment: It's `static::deleting`, not `static::deleted`! Because the delete not happened yet, just starting the proccess. Also if your add `return false` in the deleting method to the end, nothing will be deleted.

Comment: Is this boot method in your user model? You should pleace it in your model, in that model where you invoke deleting. So if you call User::where('id', 1)->delete(), than you should place it in your User model.

Comment: Yes, I have placed the boot method in my `user` model.  It's getting triggered up to after `parent::boot();` but the stuff inside `static::deleting` is not getting triggered.

Comment: @lamzozo I have copied my current `user` model above

Comment: I have also tried changing my delete method to this `$this->user->where('id', $id)->first()->delete()` as per this post: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536 but still no luck.

Comment: Is this boot method get called or inside the deleting method? I suggest to try with other models, or try with some other events like `creating`, `saving`. I tried it with laravel 5.1 and working, anyway it's strange.

Comment: It is executing, but it's a problem with my relationship models.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you wrote in your example, I'm not sure eloquent relatinships are available in this case. That's why I wrote simple query builder example.